# NFV/SDN in cloudstack

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, apache-cloudstack

I am new with the NFV+SDN technologies. I have downloaded the `OpenDayLight` and `cloudstack`. I have mininet network as underlying physical topology. I want to set up a multi cloud that must contain `cloudstack` and another IAAS technology, and finally manage the interconnection of resources created on these clouds. I already integrated `opendaylight` with `cloudstack` but still don't have a clear image on how to start.

My confusions are:
which technology can guide me to realize a multi-cloud, `NFV` or `SDN`? Also is the opendaylight the solution for this? Or there are other frameworks or projects that can help me better.
I shall be grateful to you for any information that could get me started on this project.

Comment: try these links maybe this helps https://github.com/sonata-nfv/son-emu, https://github.com/GanapathyRaman/NETWORK-MANAGEMENT-USING-SDN-and-NFV

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

OpenDayLight already supports inter-domain routing through BGP, hence having two OpenDayLight talking to each other through BGP will allow you to get L3 (IP based) traffic back-n-forth which is going to be sufficient to interconnect L3-as-a-Service tenants between the two cloud systems.

BGP (as it is today in ODL) will not cut it for L2-as-a-Service or complex multi-cloud deployments. To achieve connectivity across cloud-domains for L2aaS / Complex-tenants, you will need to

**Control Plane**: An extension to East-West signaling between SDNc of each cloud to handle L2aaS service requirements (OpenDayLight supports multiple options here)

**Data Plane**:

1. A cloud fabric that can carry L2aaS (you don't want to lose the L2aaS identifiers when you move from one domain to the other domain).
2. An anchor node (ex. DC-GW) to get SDNc to configure the data-plane L2 fabric cross-connects (through interfaces such as OVSDB, ML2 or other).

The above two bullets are not trivial work and don't expect them to be done without some customization. Not to mention that the DC-GW vendor compatibility with ODL (ML2 plugin capabilities) will define a lot of what can and can't be done.

Final point, there are a couple of companies building their SDN go-to-market around the above problem you are trying to fix (Cisco, Arista, Nokia, Ericsson ...etc.). Keep us posted with the progress you are making on that front; you may end up putting a foundation for a new framework in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such situation with one master student three years ago. She was trying to do intra-cloud computing work, where there are many resources from two or more providers needed to be managed or outsourced.

She was working on Open nebula.

To answer you on your specific questions, SDN is a network controller no more!
it responsible for installing the path in underlying switches so two hosts can communicate to each other.

NFV is responsible to manage network functions installed in the network. They could be integrated into SDN or only in a simple cloud computing Environment.

As you can see, there are nothing for both of them to help you inter connects two cloud computing environments. They only responsible to manage network component.

YOu can provide us more information about the requirements you are trying to implement.